# How to unit test ASP.Net MVC controller that has private methods in the action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around a unit testing pattern when trying to test an ASP.Net MVC controller/action.

With the following code, I am trying to write a test for the `ShowPerson()` method:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private IDataAccessBlock _dab;

    public PersonController()
        : this(new DataAccessBlock())
    { }

    public PersonController(IDataAccessBlock dab)
    {
        _dab = dab;
    }

    public ActionResult ShowPerson(PersonRequestViewModel personRequest)
    {
        var person = GetPersonViewModel(personRequest);
        return View("Person", person);
    }

    private PersonViewModel GetPersonViewModel(PersonRequestViewModel personRequest)
    {
        var personService = new CommonDomainService.PersonService(_dab);
        var dt = personService.GetPersonInfo(personRequest.Id);
        var person = new PersonViewModel();

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            person.FirstName = dt.Rows[0]r["FIRSTNAME"]);
            person.LastName = dt.Rows[0]["LASTNAME"];
        }
        return person;
    }
}
```

The test that I am using (using nUnit and Moq):

```
[Test]
public void ShowPerson_Action_Should_Return_Person_View()
{
    // Arrange
    string expected = "Person";
    Mock<PersonRequestViewModel> personRequestViewModelMock = new Mock<PersonRequestViewModel>();
    personRequestViewModelMock.SetupProperty(f => f.Id, 123456);

    Mock<IDataAccessBlock> mockDab = new Mock<IDataAccessBlock>();
    PersonController personController = new PersonController(mockDab.Object);

    // Act
    ViewResult result = personController.ShowPerson(personRequestViewModelMock.Object) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    personRequestViewModelMock.Verify();
    result.Should().Not.Be.Null();
    if (result != null) Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.ViewName, "Unexpected view name");
}
```

Everything seems to go fine, until the line `if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)` is encountered. I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I assume that there must be something funky with the way that the following two lines are written:

```
var personService = new CommonDomainService.PersonService(_dab);
var dt = personService.GetPersonInfo(personRequest.Id);
```

but I'm not sure where to go from here. I have a lot of code that would look like this. Am I doing something wrong, or is there an actual way to test this?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: Hook a debugger up and look at what's happening.

Comment: @DanielMann I had already been doing that. The `dt` is null because the `GetPersonInfo()` method is using a mocked data access block. In an answer below, @sri has pointed me in the right direction. I have added a quick question, that I am hoping he can clear up and then will accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your CommonDomainService.PersonService is some kind of webservice which is hosted in your webapplication, when you are running your tests your webapplication will not be running and service will not be accessible.
Ideally, your controller has a dependency on CommonDomainService.PersonService which you are creating in your private method,instead this should be injected into the Controller(like you do DataAccess block), and mock it up in your test method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed `private PersonViewModel GetPersonViewModel(PersonRequestViewModel personRequest)` to accept an ICommonDomainService. In my test, I added `mockCommonDomainService.Setup(x => x.GetPeronInfo(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new DataTable());` and everything works fine. However, if I `new` up a DataTable(), assign columns to it and add a row; then use this DataTable in the `.Returns()` of the mock setup, it is still `null` when testing the DataTable. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the new approach, can you please post the new code?

Comment: You were right. Everything was working. I had a bug in an earlier line in the test. Thanks so much. I learned a lot through this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

write private readonly IDataAccessBlock _dab; instead of private IDataAccessBlock _dab;

Comment: What will that help in this scenario?